# Display a home screen action without launching the app, 3DTouch Home Screen Quick Actions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to present a sharing UIActivityViewController from a 3D touch menu action on the app icon on home screen, I'm doing the following :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler{

    if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"share"]){
        NSArray *arr = @[@"https://www.woshuo.pub"];
        UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:arr applicationActivities:nil];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
        }];

    }
    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler(YES);
    }
}
```

This results is the app being launched and the UIActivityViewController displayed. What I'm trying to do is to display the UIActivityViewController without launching the app.

I saw this behaviour in popular apps like Booking and AirBnB.
For example: the apple store APP

Comment: All apps you download from the app store have a default 3D touch menu item to share that app that does that.  You can't create your own menu item that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Share action seen at the top of every App-Store-installed app's quick actions menu? (circled below)

[image: quick actions menu]

That action is provided by the system, and always shares only a link to the App Store listing for the app. All other actions (the other four in the screenshot) are provided by the app itself (whether [static or dynamic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html)), and always launch the app when chosen.

Note that in iOS 10, if you app provides a Notification Center widget (aka Today view widget), that [shows up along with the Quick Actions menu](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/widgets/) for your app on the Home screen -- if you're looking for a way to put more interactive content into your quick actions, that might be a viable route. (Note that tapping in the widget still launches your app, though.)

Comment: I want to share call system is used to share their app, but I don't open the app